# Are there some nice properties for a finite two-player game having an increasing differences utility and a decreasing differences utility?

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, reference-request, academic-graduate

Nice properties of the set of Nash equilibria can be shown for supermodular games(see [here](http://cowles.econ.yale.edu/P/cp/p08b/p0875.pdf)). But for a two-player game in which

1. Strategy spaces for two player, $S_1$ and $S_2$ are finite, and both of them are subsets of $\mathbb R$.
2. $u_1$ exhibits [increasing differences](http://web.stanford.edu/~jdlevin/Econ%20286/Supermodular%20Games.pdf) while $u_2$ exhibits decreasing differences.

What can we say about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a recent paper which may help you:
[Games with strategic complements and substitutes](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00199-015-0864-0) (Monaco and Sabarwal (2015))